How to create abbreviation like `fr<Tab>` for '\frac{}{}' in `org-cdlatex-mode`?
I want to know how can I make an abbreviation like fr, where fr<Tab> will create \frac{}{} in the math environment. I try to make an abbreviation for lim, where lim<Tab> will create \lim{} and the cursor is located between the curl brackets. I have try (setq cdlatex-env-alist'(("limit" "\\lim_{?}" nil))) and (setq cdlatex-command-alist '(("lim" "Insert fraction env" "" cdlatex-environment ("limit") t nil))) but this seems only works at the beginning of a line.

This is confusing. The title mentions fr, the body of the question ia all about lim (but the doc string says "Insert fraction env") - can you please fix the question?


Since you use doomemacs, please always add the tag doom to your questions, because
of restrictions added by the code in doomemacs.

It is better to ask doomemacs questions to their discord site, it is mentioned in documentation,
or at r/doomemacs.

Other people had same/similar problems
as you do, and, unfortunately there was not provided a working solution. In such cases it is
useful to look for alternative(s).

The lim keyword is so short that there is not already a snippet for it; however, for
your use case, such thing can be done using snippets rather complex commands in cdlatex.
See this package, you not need to disable yasnippet,
it is faster and you can add your snippet for lim easily. Take care to configure it as this:


(after! latex
    (use-package laas
    ;; copy here the snippet provided by link above
    ;; ad a hook to start it in org-mode, similar with the provided one for latex
    ;; add a snippet for `lim`))

Your snippet for lim may look as below (modify it for your use case):
"lim" (lambda () (interactive)
        (yas-expand-snippet "\\lim_{$1} $0"))

NB: It is useful to have also a second tool/IDE, if and when possible.
